# Prolog Implementation of Mergersort won't halt

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop, mergesort, failure-slice

I am a new Prolog developer and am trying to get merge sort working.The query

```
mergesort([2,1],T).
```

Will Produce

```
T=[1,2];
T=[1,2];
T=[1,2];
...
```

So Although it seems to "correctly" sort the sequence it doesn't halt

On the other hand if I had a query such as

```
mergesort([2,1],[2,1])
```

It gets into an infinite loop. I am wondering why this is the case?

```
append([H|T],LISTB,[H|LISTC]):-
    append(T,LISTB,LISTC).

split(LIST,L1,L2):-
    length(LIST,LENGTH),
    M is div(LENGTH,2),
    append(L1,L2,LIST),
    length(L1,L1LENGTH),
    (L1LENGTH =:= M).

merge(A,[],A).
merge([],B,B).
merge([A|TA],[B|TB],[A|MERGED]) :-
    A =< B,
    merge(TA,[B|TB],MERGED).
merge([A|TA],[B|TB],[B|MERGED]) :-
    B < A,
    merge([A|TA],TB,MERGED).

mergesort([],[]).
mergesort([X],[X]).
mergesort(LIST,OLIST):-
    split(LIST,L1,L2),
    mergesort(L1,OLIST1),
    mergesort(L2,OLIST2),
    merge(OLIST1,OLIST2,OLIST).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>(`append([], L, L).` was missing)</sup>

First, reduce the size of your input! The problem you get with `[2,1]` can already be observed with `[2]` and even `[]`!

```
?- mergesort([],T).
   T = []
;  T = []
;  T = []
;  T = []
;  ... .
```

So the problem seems to be that the program does not terminate. Or maybe it stops after ten answers? There is a way to better test this:

```
?- mergesort([], T), false.
   loops.
```

And if I am at it, I will add further goals into your program such that the resulting program still loops:

```
append([], L, L).
append([H|T],LISTB,[H|LISTC]):- false,
    append(T,LISTB,LISTC).

split(LIST,L1,L2):- LIST = [],
    length(LIST,LENGTH),
    M is div(LENGTH,2),
    append(L1,L2,LIST),
    length(L1,L1LENGTH),
    (L1LENGTH =:= M).

mergesort([],[]) :- false.
mergesort([X],[X]) :- false.
mergesort(LIST,OLIST):- LIST = [],
    split(LIST,L1,L2), L1 = [], L2 = [],
    mergesort(L1,OLIST1), false,
    mergesort(L2,OLIST2),
    merge(OLIST1,OLIST2,OLIST).
```

I have added goals **`false`** and **`L = []`** **which all terminate and thus will either improve termination or leave it as is**. This resulting fragment of the program is known as a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

*Because* this program loops, also your original program loops. Thus, there must be an error somewhere in the visible part. Does it really make sense that the recursive rule of `mergesort/2` applies to the empty list?

((Apart from that, split is quite inefficient as it stands.))

Answer (score 1):

Im sure this is hacky solution however it is *A* solution

```
mergesort(LIST,OLIST):-
    split(LIST,L1,L2),
    mergesort(L1,OLIST1),
    mergesort(L2,OLIST2),
    merge(OLIST1,OLIST2,OLIST),
    !.
```

Comment: Try `mergesort([], [a])` to see it looping.